# **Iam doing this in Android**How to add a index.html file to the qml project and load it in webview

Tags: android, qtwebview, qtwebchannel

```
   `Rectangle {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        border.width: 2
        border.color: "blue"

        WebView {
            id: webView
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: 5
            `**`url: "qrc:/assets/index.html"`**`
            onLoadingChanged: {
                if (loadRequest.errorString)
                    { console.error(loadRequest.errorString); }
            }
        }

        WebChannel {
            id: channel
            registeredObjects: [someObject]
        }
    }`
```

For Android[Not working]: I tried adding the index.html file by manually creating an assets folder in the root directory and then from QtCreator, added the asset folder with the html file by right click qml.qrc, open with editor, added the folder and the index.html file.

For Linux[working] - I added thie Html file in the  root directory and used url:"qc:/index.html" it worked.

I was following the steps from https://decovar.dev/blog/2018/07/14/html-from-qml-over-webchannel-websockets/
and
from [Qt WebView and WebChannel over WebSockets in QML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51313111/qt-webview-and-webchannel-over-websockets-in-qml) and from
https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/51313111

Answer (score 0):

For android, i took the following steps to make the index.html file render in  webview.

```
Step 1 - Create an android_asset folder and add the index.html file into it
Step 2 - Right click project and add the android_asset forler as "Add existing Directory".
Step 3 - update the .pro file with the following details
```

> ```
> deployment.files += android_asset/index.html
> deployment.path = /assets
> INSTALLS += deployment
> ```

Step 4 - update the follwing in the qml file where we have created the webview,

```
    WebView {
        id: webView
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 5
        url:"file:///android_asset/index.html"
        onLoadingChanged: {
            if (loadRequest.errorString)
                { console.error(loadRequest.errorString); }
        }

        WebChannel {
            id: channel
            registeredObjects: [someObject]
        }
    }
```